# Speed is key vs Speed is the key

Tags: articles, usage, spoken-english

I have been watching a TV show about cheetahs, and the narrator used the following sentence:

> Speed is key,

As far as I know, "key" is neither abstract nor uncountable. I don't understand why 'the' is omitted before 'key'.

Comment: How about [*key*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/key): "6. adjective -  [ADJECTIVE noun] - The *key* person or thing in a group is the most important one." I would say *importance* is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

**key** can be an adjective (of paramount importance, necessary, critical, crucial) or a noun.

Comment: Can we omit 'the' before an adjective?

Comment: @Chenmunka: It does answer the question. There is no need for an article before a predicate adjective.  Every single little thing does not have to be spelled out. They're learners, not idiots.

Comment: That's the reader's fault, not the writer's, @Rompey. It is the single necessary and sufficient fact to explain the usage.

Comment: @user31782: Can we omit the article before a predicate adjective? Usually (nearly always)  we *must* do so.    We don't say *This car is **the** fast* but *This car is fast*.  The sentence in your question can be paraphrased *Speed is paramount*.

Answer (score 1):

> "Speed is key!"

If you googled the phrase, you'd know that its author is an Irish producer, game commentator, and internet personality known under the pseudonym of [Jacksepticeye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacksepticeye). In one of his [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cblgt7PTgIs) he uses the phrase when going fast or wanting to go fast **in a computer game**. And of course, there, the word "key", grammar-wise, is neither abstract nor uncountable noun – it's an adjective already defined by the previous answerer.

Actually, "Speed is key" is a meme which is a cultural unit/idea/pattern of behavior that is passed from one person to another by non-genetic means (as by imitation).

An additional source [is here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/tags.php?tag=%23memes).

At the same time, if a key is also a part to be pressed by a finger that serves as one unit of a keyboard (and there may be a special key designed for the acceleration in a game), the above-mentioned person, speaking too fast, might just have skipped the definite article. You can never tell with memes.